# JSP/Servlets necessity for JSF development

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets

I am an intermediate java developer and i was tying to get to know the java web application capablities,

i want to learn JSF java EE for web application development, because am already in the field of web development using Ruby and PHP.

should i learn jsp/servlets first? or Java Web Application Frameworks do not depend on jsps and servlets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd learn JSP/Servlets since JSF is built upon that technology. Will give you a good solid understanding of the Java EE foundation.

Best tutorial on the web: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html